# using command ".." to find a file in another folder remotely

Tags: shell, command

I am creating a project with test files in it. In the test file, I need to import the class file. The structure of my project looks like this:

```
|project_name

|--main.py

|--ClassFolder

|----bla.py

|--TestFolder

|----test_bla.py
```

for example, I am going to import bla.py to test_bla.py. And I used the code in test_bla.py:

```
import sys
import unittest
sys.path.append("../")
from ClassFolder.bla import bla
```

This works fine when I call the test file locally. However, if I call it remotely, it would give me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jj/PycharmProjects/project_name/TestFolder/test_bla.py", line 4, in <module>
from ClassFolder.bla import bla
ImportError: No module named ClassFolder.bla
```

I think the problem is, when I call it remotely, the root directory ("./") is not in project_name/TestFolder/. command ".." leads me to a folder above the current one.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Locally from  which directory you are executing the script? And how are you executing it remotely with what user id?

Comment: @AbhijitPritam the local path is /home/jj/PycharmProjects/project_name/TestFolder/, which is in my home directory. And in my situation, a test environment can access to my home dir by typing home/username

Answer (score 0):

Seems like class path issue. When you execute the script remotely your remote user id account paths are not set properly. So first set `PYTHONPATH` variable for this user account in the server where you are executing the python script and also set `path` variable for this account as well.

Comment: user account is always available in this case. However, personal idea, when .. is called, the root dir is set as where I call the script but not where the script locates. So it goes above of the current dir but not above the test file.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my way of working with unit test. Instead of calling tests remotely, I create test objects for it and call it locally